# How were the propellant pipes on the Saturn V LUT routed to the service arms?

Tags: saturn-v, launchpad

I'm trying to design a model of the Saturn V Launch Umbilical Tower.  I can find pictures showing how the propellant piping runs along the service arms, and from pictures showing the pipes running up the sides of the tower can generally guess which pipes correspond to which arms (although there is some ambiguity on arms with multiple propellant pipes).

However, I've been unable to find any pictures or diagrams showing how the pipes are routed around from the supply lines on the exterior of the tower to the service arms, while avoiding all the other hardware (eg elevator, stairs, and vertical cabling runs) in the tower itself.  The largest version of the image I've linked below from Wikipedia gives some hints about if they initially go into the image or to the right but that's only part of the routing; and I haven't found anything equivalent to show the other half of the path.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Apollo_13_Saturn_V_during_rollout.jpg/785px-Apollo_13_Saturn_V_during_rollout.jpg]
[source:  [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_13_Saturn_V_during_rollout.jpg)]

Comment: Do the files linked from this page help?  http://www.savethelut.com/links.html

Comment: @Hobbes unfortunately not.  That site's one of my primary sources, but only has (some) floor-plans, but not anything showing the routing of pipes hung from the ceilings.

Comment: Is this helpful: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/High-angle_view_of_the_White_Room_and_the_Apollo_11_Command-and-Service_Module.jpg - Would you accept images of well built **plastic models** which appear authentic looking?

Comment: @Rob That particular image was new to me (I hadn't thought to look for images outside of articles before now).  I'm interested in what other modeler's may have done for potential inspiration if nothing else (and contingent on the rest of the model looking reasonably accurate), but the only one I've found with detailed pipe routing so far was done by someone who said that the routing was made up due to lack of sources.

Answer (score 2):

Since you commented that you'll accept great looking models I'll offer an answer. If a better answer is forthcoming you can change your choice of preferred / chosen answer.

Wikipedia's webpage: "[High-angle view of the White Room and the Apollo 11 Command-and-Service Module](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:High-angle_view_of_the_White_Room_and_the_Apollo_11_Command-and-Service_Module.jpg)" has this image:

[image: High-angle view of the White Room and the Apollo 11 Command-and-Service Module]

The full resolution versions of the two images below available on Wikipedia show routing of the pipes on the side to the service arms.

[image]
[Source [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_10_Roll-out_-_GPN-2000-000960.jpg)]

[image]
[Source [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_17_Pre-Launch_-_GPN-2000-000636.jpg)]

In a forum thread on [CollectSpace](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum29/HTML/000935.html) FFrench asks about the elevator. The answer by 'Spacecraft Films' refers to "Disc 1 of Apollo 8" by which I believe they mean "Apollo 8: Leaving the Cradle" (3 Disc Set). It's available for rental or purchase in used condition.

Check out Trip Niven's Flickr titled: "[Saturn V/Apollo Launch Umbilical Tower Scale Model - Model Construction Progress](https://www.flickr.com/photos/tripster7/sets/72157619198097938/)" where he documents his model building, in 150 photos, using STLut drawings.

The Kerbel Space Program has a Mod called: "[[WIP] [1.3+] Apollo Saturn V Launch Umbilical Tower (LUT) and Mobile Launcher](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/176206-wip-13-apollo-saturn-v-launch-umbilical-tower-lut-and-mobile-launcher/)" and a video demoing the animation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BROHyGNon_c) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7TldGgvNXQ) - it remains to be seen how detailed it will be when it's finished but the ability to wall through the 3D model might be useful.

The movie "For All Mankind" at [4:30](https://youtu.be/FJiHAoAru54?t=4m30s) shows a ride in the elevator with the camera pointed upward a lot of the time. The resolution of the video is great but you'll need to convert clips of it to get a series of photos from which to choose. Here's one screenshot:

[image: For All Mankind]

You can use a program like ffmpeg to convert video into a directory full of images.

Comment: I've got lots of external shots showing the piping going up the sides of the tower and along the arms (along with detailed drawings of the arms from savethelut.com ).  What I'm specifically looking for is the routing from the big bunch of pipes going up the side of the tower (and smaller bunch along the back) to the service arms.  The 1st picture you found (for the command and service module arms) along with the one In my post are the only ones I've seen that (barely) show any hits of how the pipes were routed.

Comment: I have a [build log](http://www.scalemotorcars.com/forum/large-scale-airplanes/2853-apollo-saturn-rocket-2.html) for the paper model in your middle set of pictures and a [much more detailed one from Japan](https://ranging.exblog.jp/m2012-03-01/).  On the Lego front I've got both whatsuptoday's publicly released model from Lego Ideas (probably needs 10-30h of work to swap out parts no longer available at any price to build) and Bailey's models (for sale if contacted in a private message) models.  Before it expanded into a top to bottom redesign mine started out as a few tweaks of the latter.

Comment: Bailey's design doesn't have any internal/arm piping (and doesn't appear to have used any source material beyond wikipedia and savethelut).  Whatsuptoday's was routed on the floor not the ceilings (wrong).  I've also seen pictures of [NathanR's](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/154148-moc-apollo-launch-tower-wip/&page=3) design; which is probably the most detailed Lego design that's at least semi-publicly available.  He pointed me to both paper craft models, but had no luck finding any official documents of the pipes internal routing either.

Comment: @DanNeely - I found a way to locate more images. Search for "vertical assembly building", they may not mention the LUT but it might be in the photo depending on where they are in the assembly process. I've provided links to the couple of additional photos which go off in endless directions to 1000's more photos (easier for you to search on Desktop than for me to try on mobile phone). As mentioned please feel free to delete whichever photos you want, and save SE a bit of space on the Server. All the updated photos seem to imply that those 'model photos' are somewhat accurate. GL building yours.

Comment: The unlinked Wikipedia image galleries did have a few very large images taken at the right angle to see the routing of pipes going up the side to the arms.  I have not been able to find anything comparable for the pipes running up the back of the tower.   (Haven't looked at vab related images yet, might not have time to do so until thursday.)

Comment: @DanNeely - Updated. I've added 4 paragraphs and a screenshot to the end of my answer.

Comment: I've watched the linked video, other than the 60' platform the angle was too tight to  see any piping on the interior of the tower.  I've pinged both of the additional modelers you've found inquiring about any source material they might have.  Will update if they have anything to offer.

Comment: I actually do have success of a sort to report.  At some point after I'd given up and assumed it was totally dead, the yahoogroups LUT_group moderators did approve my membership request, and it's [Cato Library](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/LUT_Group/files/Cato%20Library/) which Trip Nivem pointed me to contains a much larger collection of engineering diagrams than savethelut.com has.

Comment: It does include suitably detailed diagrams for the LH2/LOX piping.  I haven't found an equivalent for the ECS pipes, but those are well covered with pictures and are less critical.  Unfortunately, due to it's semi-private (members only access) nature, I don't feel comfortable reposting anything here.

Comment: @DanNeely - We are glad we could be of assistance, to the extent that it was possible. I hope you can appreciate 'which way the pipes go' is poorly documented, people were interested more in 'which way did the astronauts go' (and where they went when they had to go). If you had wanted diagrams of the umbilicals it would have been easy. Tower wiring and piping diagrams weren't newsworthy. You might try searching for Permits and Inspection Reports. Editing the answer to explain how/where to obtain membership might help a future visitor. Thanks for keeping us updated, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer regarding sources for information:

The Yahoo LUT group has moved to groups.io and is available here:  https://groups.io/g/LUTGroup

All of the LOX/LH2 (Side3) and ECS (Side2) internal pipe routing is available there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is valuable info in the context of the other answer, so I'm making a minor edit. The Community Bot comment isn't very helpful because this answer is basically *all a citiation*. But it isn't a complete answer, so I'll make that clear.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31784)